# Highlighting the submenu when its menu item is clicked - primefaces

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I have a primefaces menu which is dynamically generated. The url, id are set for the menuitem and added to the submenu. I need to highlight the submenu when one of its menu item is clicked. I cannot find any parent-child relation to add a styleclass to the submenu. I can only access the url of the menuitem . Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: could you provide code sample

Comment: Can't you just add an `id` to your `<p:submenu>` tag?